# Godaddy dissappearing links to App Engine Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

Three lines of code and the second is disappeared on Godaddy servers.

I use Godaddy for my domain names, and dbay in the middle is pointed at appengine apps. It never shows and will take an entire paragraph with it. This is also true of other domains pointed at my appspot.com apps. Or I am the object of sabotage and need some help here.

```
<h4><a href="https://youtu.be/YMUIL7iQ_j0">How it Works for You</a></h4 >
<H4><a href="http://dbay.cab”>Dbay.cab</a></H4 >
<H4><a href="https://www.facebook.com/solomonschariot">Like on Facebook.</a></H4 >
```

Try it yourself or see it at solomonschariotDOTcom/indexbadDOThtml

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with GoDaddy, so I can understand why their tech support would not be helpful.

You are missing a close quote after the "http://dbay.cab" href: you have a close smart quote instead. Your browser does not recognise that as closing the attribute, so it interprets everything until the next quote as being part of the URL. You can see that if you hover over the last link: the address that displays includes the tag and text from the middle link.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I get for offing a quickie typing html freehand in text edit after a long day :) Storm of course immediately flagged it. The funny thing is this morning at 12.30 I go for an eye exam :) was scheduled weeks ago :)